# Find the inverse laplace (if there is one)

Tags: laplace-transform

I need to find if $F(s)$ can be a laplace transform of a continuous exponential function:

$$F(s)=\frac{s^3}{s^3+2s^2+s+1}$$

any ideas?

Comment: Well the fact that it doesn't vanish at infinity already means there's some kind of Dirac delta going on, are you prepared for that? If not then you've probably written the problem wrong. The fact that the roots of the cubic in the denominator are really nasty also suggests you may have written the problem wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As Ian suggests, because of the equal polynomial orders in the numerator and the denominator, the inverse implicates the Dirac delta function. So the answer is no, F(s) is not a transform of a continuous exponential function.